# How do I complete the Snow Ballin' Achievement?

Tags: achievements, crimecraft-gangwars

How do I get the Snow Ballin' achievement in CrimeCraft GangWars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You complete it by getting 200 points in total in Snow Brawl matches.

After you've signed up on a realm, you might want to do a practice round first for the basic controls. They're not very complicated though, and you can jump right into the Snow Brawl event, by clicking the gun icon, selecting the events tab and pressing the FIGHT button below Snow Brawl. Here's a visual guide:

[image]

It's your basic third-person shooter. The Snow Brawl game mode is one of CrimeCraft's other game modes, but nobody has any ammo, and everyone has infinite snowball grenades.

However, note that round points **do not count** towards the achievement — for example, if you get a game mode with control points, holding them will not be your objective for the achievement.

You do get (personal) points for:

- Killing other players (this is where most of your points come from)
- Capping control points, if any

So if there are control points, it is in your best interest to capture them, but then not *defend* them. After all, the sooner they fall, the sooner you can recapture them.

Anyway, on to the killing. In this game mode, any and all weapons are disabled, but you have a snowball grenade, which is Ability #1 (bound to <kbd>F1</kbd> by default). This is incredibly awkward, so you might want to rebind it to something more accessible, like, say, the <kbd>F</kbd> key.

All that remains is to throw said grenades at jerks that are not your color. Some tips:

- Only direct hits from snowball grenades hurt, but they're always an instant kill.
- Trying to sneak up close on unsuspecting or distracted players is probably the easiest way to score a kill. Snowballs are quite slow, so ranged kills are pretty much always luck shots.
- Do not ever stand still. Fidget around. Sprint if you're moving.
- The dodge roll (direction key + <kbd>Space</kbd> by default) may not be your bread, but it is certainly your butter. Use it constantly and hope you're up against someone who doesn't know it.
- Unless you're close up, don't let 1-on-1 situations drag on too long. You're about to get snowball'd in the back.

After you've accumulated 200 points in total, the achievement will unlock.

Comment: Even easier, bind the snowball from F1 to Mouse1, and bind fire from Mouse1 to Mouse2 (you can't shoot, but you need to press fire to respawn).

Answer (score 1):

On the battle menu, there should be a tab all the way to the right titled "events"
the snow ball brawl event will be there and all you have to do is hit battle.